# Use a DecisionTree throughout whole lifetime in C# .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, decision-tree

I have a webapplication in development. I'm thinking about using a DecisionTree to analyse certain things.

The DecisionTree has to be created and will be used in different fases. E.g. in a controller something will be compared/checked and a certain view will be returned.

Do I create this DecisionTree at the start of my app and somehow get a reference to it in all my controllers? Or do I recreate it again whenever I use it? I'm guessing the reference method is the best one since a tree gets created on a datatable which consumes memory, etc.. to process

Comment: Is this an ASP web-application?

Comment: It's a ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: May want to add that tag to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using som IoC Container (f.e. Ninject) just register this class as singleton and set as dependency for controllers.

f.e.

```
kernel.Bind<IShogun>().To<Shogun>().InSingletonScope();
```

[object scopes from Ninject documentation](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes)

And set it as dependenty in MVC controller, by constructor injection:

```
MyController(IShogun shogun)
{ ... }
```

or by property injection:

```
[Inject]
IShogun { get; set; }
```

If you're not using IoCC - please start :)
I prefer Ninject but you have quite big choice in IoCCs.

Comment: I do use Ninject at the moment. Good idea to use it. I'm going to look at some more answers and then choose the one I think is best.

Comment: Accepted this because it uses Ninject AND singleton.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a good place for a Singleton.

Might be worth reading up on the Singleton Pattern if you haven't used one before.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

You could initally create the singleton in the Application_Start of Global.aspx if you wanted to, if you want to set some initial state when the Web Application is started.